# How INSERT data in two tables in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have master table for data:
table name: `master_tbl`

`id` is auto increment

```
id  name        age sex
1   Mario       13  M
2   Luigi       14  M
3   Princess    13  F
```

> INSERT INTO master_tbl (name, age, sex) VALUES ('Mario', 13, 'M');

then i have other table for activity
table name: `activity`

id is anti increment also

> id_ref should get the id from master_tbl

```
id  id_ref  exercise    duration
1   1       Running     1
2   1       Swimming    2
3   1       Biking      1
4   2       Biking      2
5   2       Rowing      1
6   3       Running     2
```

How to insert data into 2 tables where in activity table, it will get the `id` from master table.
my goal is to use it as grouper of data that it is belong to that specific request in master table.

thanks.

Comment: i don't think mysql has that feature wherein you get the last insert id and use that and insert it on another table in just one query. it has to be separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LAST_INSERT_ID() function will return the last auto incremented value.

```
INSERT INTO master_tbl (name, age, sex) VALUES ('Mario', 13, 'M');

INSERT INTO activity (id_ref, exercise, duration) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Running', 1);
```

If you just want to know what the value, you can `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`